# Java: How to drag and drop on a TrayIcon?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

How can I catch a drop event of a text / file / any other DataFlavor onto a `java.awt.TrayIcon` (placed in a `java.awt.SystemTray`)?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this is not supported yet (Java 1.7).
If anyone is interested, I have created a feature request [Sun Feature Request 7119272](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7119272) - you can monitor progress and vote for it if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

what if you add a mousemotionlistener to the TrayIcon and react on a drop floating over the TrayIcon. Then when the mouse is over the TrayIcon's mousemotionlistener will display a JList with Drag&drop support which in turn will receive the droppable.

Comment: Thanks, it's a nice idea and I tried playing with you suggestion but I couldn't find a way to make the TrayIcon display anything.

Answer (score 0):

try the code below. It fires whenever the mouse moves over the trayicon.

```
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener
    (
       new java.awt.event.AWTEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void eventDispatched(java.awt.AWTEvent event)
          {
              if (event.getID() == java.awt.event.MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED)
              {
                    // add here your stuff
              }
          }//eventDispatched
       }//AWTEventListener
    ,  java.awt.AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK
    );
```

Comment: to be more precise: the code I just pasted for you, will fire whenever you drop a droppable on the TrayIcon. Once you release the droppable you will enter into the if-statement above.

Comment: Thanks but the code you provided fires every time the mouse is moved over any component of my Swing application including the tray icon. If you believe in the solution you suggested, please try to write a full example - I couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

you must extend your TrayIcon and add the part I gave you to this extended TrayIcon. This way it will fire only for move-events of your extended trayicon. The rest i leave to you.

Comment: further on, you can add a simple if-statement to process only events from the component of your interest. Of course this is not very nice, but dont forget that this supposedly acts as a workaround as long as a direct drag and drop is not supported